# Redundant Conditional logic

Tags: angular

I have the same conditional block which is written twice in the confirmation method below. I basically need to combine both the logic in way that functionality works and redundant checks are removed.

```
public confirmation = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve') => {
     if (!this.showMessage
       && ((type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes)
         || (type !== 'Approve'))) {
       this.showMessage = true;
       return;
     }

     if (!this.message
       && ((type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes)
         || (type !== 'Approve'))) {
       this.messageService.add('Message is required.', 'warning');
       return;
     }


    if (type === 'Approve') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.approvalMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reset') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.resetMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reject') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.rejectMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    }

  }
```

The only difference is that the first one is checking showMessage variable and the second one is checking message variable. Both of them are false by default. The main purpose of showMessage variable is to control the visibility
of the text box in the ui. The second variable comment is used to check if user has entered anything in the text box. This is to ensure that the text box is mandatory. The first time when the user clicks the button, the text box
is made visible since the showMessage is set to true.As you can also see the code exits because of the return statement. When the user clicks the button the second time, the first block is skipped and in the second block 
it checks if comments are entered and the code exits when it run the return method. The second condition block on hits if the user hasnt entered any text.

I am trying to combine the logic of the these two blocks but whats happening is that its checking for the second condtion in the first click itself. What could be a possible solution to this ?

Attempted solution

```
  if (!this.showMessage
        ||!this.message
        && ((type === 'Approve' && this.permissions.ViewNotes)
        || (type !== 'Approve'))) {
        this.showMessage = true;


      if (!this.message) {
        this.messageService.add('Message is required.', 'warning');  
      }  
      return;
    }



    if (type === 'Approve') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.approvalMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reset') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.resetMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    } else if (type === 'Reject') {
      this.confirmationDialog.show(this.rejectMessage, type, () => this.confirm(type));
    }

  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing redundant check conditions in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846500/removing-redundant-check-conditions-in-angular)

Comment: Btw this is not an angular question, more like a logic question

Answer (score 0):

Here's My go at it

```js
(type) => {
    let A = type === 'Approve';
    let B = this.permissions.ViewNotes;

    if ((!A || B)) {
        if (!this.showMessage) {
            //TODO
            return;
        }
        if (!this.message) {
            //TODO
            return;
        }
    }

    switch (type) {
        case 'Approve':
            // Todo
            break;
        case 'Reset':
            // Todo
            break;
        case 'Reject':
            // Todo
            break;
    }
}
```